# Realizar consulta SQL com duas chaves estrangeiras da mesma tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Estou criando um sistema de reconhecimento para empresa e já estava quase terminando, ja tem algum tempo que estou tentando realizar esta consulta mas não conseguir.

Possuo as seguintes tabelas:

Colaborador: id_colab,nome_colab e outros dados que não vou utilizar nesta consulta.

Ex: (5, "Gabriel de Almeida");
    (6, "Jose da Silva");

Nesta tabela tenho os valores cadastrados das chaves de reconhecimento

keyfix: id_key,name_key

Ex: (12, "Gentileza");

E por ultimo tenho um tabela onde só tenho chave estrangeira:

key_users: id_keyu,value_keyu (chave estrangeira vindo de keyfix), user_create_keyu (chave estrangeira vindo de Colaborador), user_recieve_keyu(chave estrangeira vindo de Colaborador).

Ex: (1, 12, 5, 6);

Na consulta eu precisava trazer o nome da chave (no exemplo "Gentileza") o nome do colaborador que recebe e o que está entregando porem quando executo esta query não me retorna nada:

```
SELECT id_keyu,name_key,nome_colab FROM keys_users,keyfix,colaborador WHERE id_key = value_keyu AND id_colab =  user_recieve_keyu AND id_colab = user_create_keyu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom quero agradecer a todos que se dispuseram a ajudar.

Eu resolvi depois de uma ajuda do meu irmão e tive que usar duas subquery, pode não ser o mais rápido porem funciona.

Eis as solução:

```
select k.name_key,(select c.nome_colab from colaboradores c where ku.user_create_keyu=c.id_colab) as criador,(select c.nome_colab from colaboradores c where ku.user_recieve_keyu=c.id_colab) as recebe from keys_users ku join keyfix k on ku.value_keyu=k.id_key;
```

Edit: Meu professor de Banco de Dados me deu uma solução bem mais otimizada.

```
SELECT id_keyu,name_key,c1.nome_colab , c2.nome_colab
FROM keys_users,keyfix,colaborador c1 , colaborador c2
WHERE id_key = value_keyu AND c1.id_colab =  user_recieve_keyu AND c2.id_colab = user_create_keyu;
```

Comment: Outra possibilidade é utilizar junção (JOIN) mas com a tabela Colaborador participando da query com dois papéis: "recieve" e o "create". Algo do tipo: `SELECT create.id_keyu, create.name_key, recieve.id_keyu, recieve.name_key, nome_colab 
FROM keyfix 
 INNER JOIN keys_users ON key_users.value_keyu = keyfix.id_key
 INNER JOIN colaborador create ON key_users.user_create_keyu = create.id_colab
 INNER JOIN colaborador recieve ON key_users.user_recieve_keyu = recieve.id_colab

`.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi de sua consulta, você pesquisa pelo campo "id_key" (comparando com o campo "value_keyu") e pelo campo "id_colab" (comparando com os campos "user_recieve_keyu" e "user_create_keyu"). Pode ser que nesta pesquisa pelo "id_colab" esteja o problema, já que você quer que o valor exista nos dois campos, eu imagino que o que você quer seja que o valor existe em um dos campos.

Tente fazer a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT id_keyu,name_key,nome_colab FROM keys_users,keyfix,colaborador WHERE id_key = value_keyu AND (id_colab =  user_recieve_keyu OR id_colab = user_create_keyu)
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso eu recebo registros duplicados contendo o "recieve" e o "create"  em diferentes rows.